# jQuery, AJAX PHP Contact Form

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, forms

I've been looking through thread after thread in hope of solving this problem but no luck, basically I have a very simple contact form which works fine, but when I try and make it process through jQuery AJAX no email gets sent yet the success callback triggers.

The thing that's stopping it from working is that all code is on the same page (index.php), there's no separate page for form process PHP, so now all code is on the same page I'm having to add an if statement around the PHP `if (!empty($_POST['contact-submit'])) {}` which I wouldn't have to if the PHP was being called from its own file. I don't want the PHP on in a separate file, everything needs to be on one page, if anyone has any idea at all how to get past this I would appreciate it a lot as this is driving me crazy!

HTML:

```
<form class="contact-form island" method="post" action="">
  <ul class="form-fields">
    <li>
      <label>Your Name</label>
      <input class="text-input" type="text" name="name" required value="TEST NAME">
    </li>
    <li>
      <label>Your Email</label>
      <input class="text-input" type="email" name="email" required value="email@gmail.com">
    </li>
    <li>
      <label>Subject</label>
      <input class="text-input" type="text" name="subject" required value="TEST SUBJECT">
    </li>
    <li>
      <label>Message</label>
      <textarea rows="7" name="message" required>MESSAGE</textarea>
    </li>
    <li>
      <input class="submit-input" type="submit" value="Send" name="contact-submit">
    </li>
  </ul>
</form>
```

PHP:

```
<?php
  if (!empty($_POST['contact-submit'])) {
    $name = trim(stripslashes($_POST['name'])); 
    $email = trim(stripslashes($_POST['email'])); 
    $subject = trim(stripslashes($_POST['subject'])); 
    $message = trim(stripslashes($_POST['message'])); 

    $email_from = $email;
    $email_to = 'email@gmail.com';

    $body = 'Name: ' . $name . "\n\n" . 'Email: ' . $email . "\n\n" . 'Subject: ' . $subject . "\n\n" . 'Message: ' . $message;

    $success = mail($email_to, $subject, $body, 'From: <'.$email_from.'>');

    echo '<p>Email Sent!</p>';
  }
?>
```

jQuery:

```
$(function() {

  var form = $('.contact-form');
  form.submit(function () {
    $.ajax({
      type: form.attr('method'),
      url: form.attr('action'),
      data: form.serialize(),
      success: function() {
        $.fancybox({'content': 'Email Sent!'});
      }
    });
    return false;
  });

});
```

Comment: Try giving your form an `ID` name instead of a class set in your jQuery. Then, change `$('.contact-form')` to `$('#contact-form_id')` or something of the sorts. That might be the problem. Give it a try.

Comment: try this `if (!empty($_POST['email'])) {`  this would also validate if email is empty

Comment: @Fred Tried with no luck, as I said, everything works fine if the form is pointing to the PHP via an external file, so something like that couldn't be the problem.

Comment: try `action="index.php"`

Comment: @MohammadAdil Tom wants everything in `one` file as stated in his question, and not make an external call.

Comment: He has all things in index.php , and this will not make external call, this is just to make sure he gets correct url in ajax call ` url: form.attr('action'),`

Comment: What is action="" suppose to do? Did you leave it blank on intention?

Answer (score 0):

I was bored I made you a working one based on a little of your code and a little of mine: http://pastie.org/private/zsh9jqej1zkdpeouditww

Couple quick notes: It does give feedback to the user based on their submission so if something is blank it kicks it back and lets them retry. I put a "loading image" in there in case you want to use that... In essence to prevent people from spamming the button. On my server it was click => returned almost instantly, doesn't mean that's always the case.

NOTE: Edit line 48 with your PHP file's name.

Comment: This is great, thanks a lot for putting your time into creating that, I really appreciate it, but as I said above everything needs to be in the on file (index.php) so no external PHP files.

Comment: It's one file... It just needs to know it's own name (line 48 specifies what page to push the content to, in this case it's all one file)... that said you could put <?php echo basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?> instead and it'd effectively work no matter what you named the file.

Answer (score 0):

in the jQuery-ajax part:
`url: form.attr('action')` points at the action-attribute in the form, but that is empty in the html-form.

```
<form class="contact-form island" method="post" action="">
```